# Change image for each day of month

Tags: jquery

I am making a count down to christmas web app. Would like to automatically change an image for each day of the month, does anyone know a way of doing this with Jquery?

Comment: Do you want to show a different image each day, but have the same image at for example 20th of november and december, or a different image each month and day?

Comment: it will only be for December, different image each day

Comment: Check the answers, that will work, please not I made 2 edits, in order to actually fix it. The below code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<img src="default_image.png" id="img" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = 
                {
                    1 : "image_day1.png",   // 1st of december : "path to image"
                    2 : "image_day2.png",   // 2nd of december : "path to image"
                    3 : "image_day3.png"    // 3rd of december : "path to image"
                    // keep doing this until your final date (probably 24th, 25th or 26th)
                };

    var date = new Date(); // new Date() instance
    var day = date.getDate(); // get current day

    $("#img").attr("src", images[day]);
});
```

*Edit 1: Typo in date.GetDay() - fixed*

*Edit 2: Wrong function, changed date.getDay() to date.getDate()*